# ORDER BY with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am currently working on a script which can sort a database table by the users input.

So, a user can choose a column (via selectbox) and then the whole mysql table should be displayed with the order  of the selectbox value.

**My current code (`$order` is the user input)**

Sorry for this formatting, im on a mobile device :/

```
$order = "user_id"; //user input

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id, username, realname, auth_lvl, usercolor, activated, ban FROM users ORDER BY ?");

$sql->bind_param('s', $order);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($id, $username, $realname, $auth_lvl, $usercolor, $activated, $ban);
$sql->store_result();

while ($sql->fetch()) {
    //echo...
}
```

**The problem**

It doesn't matter what `$order` (ORDER BY part) is, I always get this order of ids: 3, 4, 5, 30, 29

Comment: I'm not sure if parameters are allowed for that part of queries from php libraries, but I am fairly certain MySQL's `PREPARE`d statements don't allow that.

Comment: Prepared statements dont allow placeholders for ordering attribute

Comment: How could I do this in an other way? Maybe with a normal query but only allowing a few strings for that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input parameter is 'foo', then your SQL is equivalent to

```
SELECT user_id, username, realname, auth_lvl, usercolor, activated, ban 
FROM users
ORDER BY 'foo'
```

Which of course means that the rows can be in any order. You cannot use parameters for things like `order by` clauses and table names. In this case you would need to actually prefix the value of the column to the string.

```
$q = 'SELECT user_id, username, realname, auth_lvl, usercolor, activated, ban FROM users ORDER BY ' . $order;
```

This is obviously prone to SQL injections, so you need to manually make sure that the column name is valid:

```
$valid_col = in_array($order, ['username', 'realname', ...], true);
```

And then only execute the query if the result is true.